# How can I convert a Rmd document to a jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to convert a rmarkdown `.Rmd` document to a jupyter notebook `.ipynb`.
I found that converting from jupyter to rmd is easy using as described in [reference page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/convert_ipynb.html) but for some reason (...) the `Rstudio` team did not do the other way.

For instance I would like to convert

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "statquant"
date: "03/09/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: I don't think you can do that without losing information. As a very simple example, Jupyter notebooks don't support chunk options like `echo=FALSE` for individual chunks (i.e. cells).

Comment: @YihuiXie loosing some information is fine, something that would create markdown cells and code cells would already be great

Comment: @YihuiXie it seems that this tool: https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext does pretty cool stuff ! I'll check it out

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After checking, the silver bullet seems to be [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext)
It allows you to convert from or to `markdown`, `rmarkdown`, `python`, `ipynb`, etc.

This can actually allow you a pretty neat workflow

1. write a simple R script, `script.R`, that [you can spin](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/) into a `Rmd` document
2. use `knitr::spin('script.R', knit = FALSE)` to transform it to `Rmd`
3. use `jupytext --to notebook script.Rmd` to create `script.ipynb`
4. share or execute the notebook

Comment: to convert from `.ipynb` to `.Rmd` or `.R`: use this code
`jupytext notebook.ipynb --output notebook.R`
`jupytext notebook.ipynb --output notebook.Rmd`;

Comment: The question is asking how to convert from `.Rmd` to `.ipynb` not the other way around

Comment: Furthermore, @SumanthLazarus' comment doing the opposite going from a `.ipynb` to `.Rmd` could be improved by using the rmarkdown pacakge directly from R: `rmarkdown:::convert_ipynb(file_to_convert)` https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/convert_ipynb.html

Comment: @Ricky that's great find I did not know this existed, I wonder why they do not create a convert_to_ipynb so we can have it both ways in R

Comment: @statquant I was wondering the exact same thing. Probably just outside of the scope of what the rmarkdown package does, but it would be pretty useful to have the functionality for sure.

Comment: How do make jupytext execute the cells as its converting?

Answer (score 4):

[sos-rmarkdown](https://github.com/vatlab/sos-rmarkdown) provides yet another Rmarkdown to Jupyter notebook converter. The unique features include its support for inline expressions using [markdown-kernel](https://github.com/vatlab/markdown-kernel), use of multiple kernels in one notebook (using a [SoS kernel](https://github.com/vatlab/sos-notebook)) to accommodate code blocks in multiple languages, and the ability to execute generated notebook using [sos-papermill](https://github.com/vatlab/sos-papermill). It also uses cell meta data to control the display of input and output of code blocks in Jupyter Lab and exported HTML reports.

To use this tool, you can install `sos-rmarkdown` from `pip` or `conda-forge`, then run the converter with command

```
sos convert input.Rmd output.ipynb
```

or use option `--execute` to execute the converted notebook

```
sos convert input.Rmd output.ipynb --execute
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `sos-rmarkdown`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way.

The detailed answer (to convert .rmd to .ipynb) is described here: https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/10012123

TL;DR

Use a 3rd-party Python package `notedown` with `sed` command as follows:

1) Install a 3rd-party python package which does the conversion for us

```
$ pip install notedown
```

2) Use the installed package to convert from your *.Rmd file (or *.md) to *.ipynb and run the terminal command:

```
$ notedown example.Rmd | sed '/%%r/d' > example.ipynb
```