# How to switch to R kernel from Python kernel in Jupyter?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I converted an R markdown file(no Python code in it) into an .ipynb file referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796157/3552975):

> use `jupytext --to notebook script.Rmd` to create `script.ipynb`

But when I open the `script.ipynb` in Jupyter I found that the kernel is python3:

[image]

It seems that there is no method for me to switch from Python3 kernel to R, eventhough I can create an R environment in the same Jupyter notebook.

[image]

Any way to switch the .ipynb file to run in the R environment?

I tried many % or %% commands but all failed.

I tried `%%R` and here is the error:

> UsageError: Cell magic `%%R` not found.

and I also tried `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`, and the error reads that:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('load_ext', 'rpy2.ipython')

Comment: in the python notebook, at the very top chunck, include `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` then for any R chunck you want to run just add `%%R` and run the code

Comment: You cannot change the whole notebook. That is because the notebook contains python code and not R code. How do you expect the compiler to transform the code for you? You will rather have to change the kernel yourself and write the equivalent R code

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried the two methods, and please see the update.

Comment: To get rpy2 `%%R` magic you would need to install rpy2 in the first place: https://rpy2.github.io

Answer (score 0):

There is a button: kernel -> change kernel -> R

[image]